# How to cancel Unary service in gRPC?

Tags: java, grpc

How can I cancel and terminate a server-side running gRPC service from the client side?

JAVA & gRPC

server:

```
Context context = Context.current();
for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
    Thread.sleep(1000);
     System.out.println(i + " " + context.isCancelled());
}
```

client:

```
listenableFuture.cancel(true);
```

context.isCancelled is true but the thread is not really canceled

Comment: What do you mean by canceling the server thread? When the Context on the server side is canceled, the RPC is terminated and you are done with that RPC. Threads running the service code are from a thread pool, they are not aimed to be terminated after finishing the RPC.

Comment: If you've provided a custom executor to the [ServerBuilder](https://javadoc.io/doc/io.grpc/grpc-api/latest/io/grpc/ServerBuilder.html), you are responsible to shutdown the executor.

Comment: For example, in the code above, I want to stop the loop from running the server on the client side.

example:
client: request run (for 1 to 15);
server: run (for 1 to 15);
client: stop (for);
server: stop (for loop);

Comment: I don't understand, can you make your example more concrete? If your question is to exit the code execution in the middle of the service implementation when the RPC is being canceled, it's the service implementation's responsibility to abort the work as this is asynchronous. Java has no real way of interrupting currently running code.